# where do the browser web api's run in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, asynchronous, settimeout

where do the browser web api's run  in Javascript like setTimeout ?

Do they run in some other environment or they take the help of javascript single  thread ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

They run outside of the JavaScript runtime. Those "Web API's" are executed within the browser's Web API execution space.

`setTimeout()` for example, is a method of the `window` object (it can also be invoked as `window.setTimeout()`). `window` is not at all part of JavaScript (it's a browser object) and anything you ask the `window` to do for you is handled outside of the JavaScript runtime and by the browser's other capabilities. **The request for the Web API call originates from within the JavaScript environment, but the execution of the API call actually runs outside of it.**

This is the very reason that we can have asynchronous behavior in web applications. While the JavaScript runtime (which is a synchronous environment that can only do one thing at a time) is doing its one thing, the browser can be doing something else.

`setTimeout()`, `alert()`, `navigator.geolocation`, `XMLHttpRequest` are all examples of Web APIs that run outside of the JS engine.

Here are some **[other Web API's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API)** and **[here is a great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)** that explains this in the context of timers specifically.

Comment: Is the same way the c++ api's are handled in node js environment which event loop takes care of .

Comment: @PiyushBiswel Yes, although the particular implementation details are not standardized, the general process is the same.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, can you please clear my doubt, setTimeout is window object or web API?

Comment: @Mano `window` is an object provided by all browsers. `setTImeout()` is a method of `window` and is considered a Web API. There are aspects of `window` which have never been standardized, so the object itself isn't considered the API, but many of its methods are.

Answer (score 0):

The following series of events occur when the [API calls are made](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ):

- When the browser makes an API call, the API call is placed in the call stack
- API call is placed in the browser's web APIs stack for execution in the background
- While the API call is being executed in web APIs background, the render queue tasks are passed to the call stack by the event loop (assuming all tasks in call stack are complete) - this means the render queue is not actively paused hence the browser is not freeze
- Once the API call is completed, the results are placed to the callback queue
- If the call stack is clear, the results of the API response are placed to the call stack and the API response handler is executed by the call stack

Do comment if you need any clarification

Answer (score 0):

**APIs in client-side JavaScript:**

To understand how browser APIS works, first, you have to clear concept about **execution stack**, **event loop** and **message queue**

Client-side JavaScript, in particular, has many APIs available to it — these are not part of the JavaScript language itself, rather they are built on top of the core JavaScript language, providing you with extra superpowers to use in your JavaScript code. They generally fall into two categories:

Browser APIs are built into your web browser and are able to expose data from the browser and surrounding computer environment and do useful complex things with it. 
For example, the Web Audio API provides JavaScript constructs for manipulating audio in the browser — taking an audio track, altering its volume, applying effects to it, etc. In the background, the browser is actually using some complex lower-level code (e.g. C++ or Rust) to do the actual audio processing. But again, this complexity is abstracted away from you by the API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Introduction

```
 <script>
        const second = () =>{
            console.log("How are you doing");
        }
        const first = () =>{
            console.log("Hi there");
            second();
            console.log("The End");

        }
        first();
    </script>
```

Above example is an example of Synchronous JavaScript, where the first function is executed, logs "Hi There!" to the console, calls the second function, which then prints "How are you doing?" to the console,
nd then finally "The end" is logged to the console One instruction after the other in a Synchronous way.

**Now let's try by an example with setTimeout which is a web API. considering bellow example**

```
<body>
    <script>
        const second = () =>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                console.log("Async Hi there");
            }, 2000)
        }
        const first = () =>{
            console.log("Hi there");
            second();
            console.log("The End");

        }
        first();
    </script>
</body>
```

**Output:**
[image]

Now above one involves some Asynchronous JavaScript. Again the first function gets called, logs "Hi There!" to the console, and then calls the second function. Now this function calls the Set Timeout function, which is basically like a timer that will execute the callback function that we passed into it, after 000 milliseconds. However, this will not make the code stop for two seconds, but instead, the function returns, goes back to the first function and logs "The end". Then after the two seconds actually have passed, Async "Hi There!" is logged to the console.
Now, why does the code move on, instead of waiting for the timer to finish?

Well, before I discuss with you how and why this actually works behind the scenes, let me quickly explain to you another example. Suppose we select an image from our DOM and pass it into a Process Large Image function,
that we created. We know that this function is gonna take some time
to process the image. And just like before we don't want the code to have to wait. So we don't want it to stop while the image is processing,
because that would be terrible in some situations. What we do here is to also pass in a Callback function, that we want to be called as soon as the function is done processing. And just like that we have created Asynchronous code.

That is the whole philosophy behind Asynchronous JavaScript. We do not wait for a function to finish its work, and then do something with the result. Instead, we let that function do its job in the background,
so that we can move on with the code execution. We then also pass in a callback function, that will be called as soon as the main function
has done whatever it had to do. We then move on immediately,
so that the code is never blocked. Which means that it can keep processing the code in a Synchronous way, line by line. Because if the code is actually blocked, then nothing really works on the page during that time.
For example you can't click any buttons, or anything like that. So, in summary, we can use callback functions to defer actions into the future.

In order to make our code non-blocking. But how does that actually work
behind the scenes of JavaScript? Well, that's where the Event Loop comes in. the Event Loop is part of the bigger picture of what happens behind the scenes of JavaScript, when we call functions and handle events like DOM events.
Event Loop, as well as the Web APIs, which together with the Execution Stack and the Message Queue make up our JavaScript runtime. This runtime is responsible for how JavaScript works behind the scenes as it executes our code. It's extremely important to understand how all these pieces
fit together in order to execute Asynchronous JavaScript.

Let's now take a look at how the code from the last example
is executed inside our JavaScript engine, line by line.

It starts by calling the first function, and as we already know,
an Execution Context for that function is put on top of the Execution Stack, which can also be called the Call Stack.
[image]

In the next line of code, the console dot log function is called and a new Execution Context is created and the text is logged to the console.
Then the function returns and the Execution Context pops off the stack.00
[image]

Moving on to the second function, a new Execution Context is created
and in the next line the Set Timeout function is called. Which causes yet another Execution Context to be created.

[image]

Now, before we move on, where does this **Set Timeout** function actually come from? It's part of something called the **Web APIs**. Which actually live **outside the JavaScript engine itself**. Stuff like DOM manipulation methods, Set Timeout, HTTP requests for AJAX, geolocation, local storage and tons of other things, actually live outside of the JavaScript engine
We just have access to the because they are also in a JavaScript runtime
This is exactly where the time will keep running for two seconds, asynchronously of course so that our code can keep running without being blocked.
[image]

When we call the Set Timeout function the timer is created, together of course with our callback function Right inside the Web APIs environment.
And there it keeps sitting unti it finishes its work all in an Asynchronous way.

[image] 
[image]

The callback function is not called right not but instead it stays attached to the timer until it finishe
And since the timer keeps working basically in the background, we don't have to wait and can keep executing our code. Next up, the Set Timeout function returns, pops off the stack and so does the Execution Context of the second function Which now returns as well and we are back to the initial first function. Now we just log the end to the console
and we give ourselves a new Execution Context, print the text to the console and pop the text off again.

Next the function returns and we are back to our original state
Right now we have executed all our code in a Synchronous way,and have the timer run Asynchronously in the background. Let's suppose that our two seconds have passe and the timer disappear. But what happens to our callback function no **Well, it simply moves to the Message Queue**
where it waits to be execute as soon as the Execution Stack is empty
This is exactly what happens with DOM events.

In the case of DOM events our event listeners sit in the Web APIs environment, waiting for a certain event to happen And as soon as that event then happen then the callback function is placed on a Message Queue
ready to be execute.

[image]

Alright, so how are these callback function in the Message Queue executed
And that's where, finally, the Event Loop comes in. The job of the Event Loop is to constantly monitor the Message Queue and the Execution Stack,
and to push the first callback function in line onto the Execution Stack, as soon as the stack is empty. In our example here, right now the stack is empty, right And we have one callback waiting to be execute
And the event loop takes the callback and pushes it onto the stack
where a new Execution Context is created for that function.

That's what the event loop does. Inside that callback function now,
we simply run the log function, which logs Async "Hi There!" to the console. Then the context pops off the stack and we're done! Now if there were some callbacks waiting right now like data coming back from an AJAX request or the handler of a DOM even then the Event Loop would continue pushing them onto the stack until all of them were processed.

Comment: In the example where to mentioned an expensive task - "Process Large Image function". Even if we do this task asynchronously, but when the synchronous image processing starts executing then it will block the code, right?

Comment: @skyhavoc Progressive Image Loader is a good option. If you have multiple images on the same page then you need to build  both Lazy Loader and Progressive Image Loader.